# MongoDB Get collection data types

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection with let say persons.
I get the collection like:

```
_collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>('persons')`;
```

That gives me the collection and if I do:

```
_collection.AsQueryable();
```

It gives me the data. All fine so far.

But Is there a way to get any info on the datatypes so the client can do his magic?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you need to use `typeof` which will return a data type. But there is a difference if you are working in BSON or JSON on terms of data types. I would suggest you take a look at the docs on data types.  (Am on my cell so just search for it). Hope that helps